# What do these strings in the NWN2 client extension readme mean?

Tags: neverwinter-nights-2

I am trying to play Neverwinter Nights 2 multiplayer.
To that end I downloaded *clientextension_latest.zip* from [here](https://neverwintervault.org/project/nwn2/other/nwn2-client-extension).

I'm having trouble understanding the *ClientExtensionReadme.txt*. I can't figure out exactly how to implement strings like "*NWLauncher.exe +connect mynwn2pw.example.com*" or "*NWLauncher.exe -dmc +connect mynwn2pw.example.com +password dmpassword*". I'm guessing these strings are some sort of shortcut, but even that confuses me.
In short, it seems that the *readme.txt* assumes I know more than than I do. I'm not even sure I know enough to ask a proper question. I need a step by step direction from a book called NWN2 Client Extension for Dummies. I read that this "client extension" is THE best way to do NWN 2 multiplayer currently, anno 2019.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96969/discussion-between-joachim-and-wrigglenite).

Answer (score 2):

**There are a few ways you can <s>do this, and the choice is yours</s> add parameters to the [NWN2 Client Extension](https://neverwintervault.org/project/nwn2/other/nwn2-client-extension).**

Before using any of the methods explained:

- Unpack the latest *clientextension_latest.zip* file.
- Note the folder where you unpacked the files (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> it for direct reference).

### Using a shortcut:

**This is the easiest method.**

- Right-click the file *NWLauncher.exe*, select '*Send to*', and '*Desktop (create shortcut)*' from the submenu.
- Go to your Desktop, and right-click the created shortcut, and choose 'Properties'.
- In the window that pops up, find the '*Target:*' field.
  Here you can make the adjustments you need:

  - Be sure to first wrap the current content in quotation marks (e.g.: `"C:\ClientExtension_Latest\NWLauncher.exe"`, instead of `C:\ClientExtension_Latest\NWLauncher.exe`).
  - After that entire string (including the added quotation marks), you can set parameters:
  - `"C:\ClientExtension_Latest\NWLauncher.exe" -dmc +connect mynwn2pw.example.com +password dmpassword`
- Hit '*Apply*' or '*OK*', and run the client using that shortcut.

### Using a batch file:

This solution is a bit harder, but allows for easier customization.

- Open "Notepad", or "Notepad++".
- Start with typing `@echo off`, to prevent the file from showing any feedback.
- Start a new line, and type `start`, followed by <kbd>Space</kbd>, the folder you unpacked the archive to (or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>), and `NWLauncher.exe` (e.g. `start C:\ClientExtension_Latest\NWLauncher.exe`).
- Add parameters to that line (e.g. `C:\ClientExtension_Latest\NWLauncher.exe -dmc +connect mynwn2pw.example.com +password dmpassword`).
- Start a new line, and type `exit` to close the command line popup after starting the client.

### Using the Command Prompt:

**Basically doing the exact same thing in a harder (but so much *cooler*) way.**

- Go to the Windows Start menu, and type `cmd`. Right-click the result "Command Prompt", and select "Open as Administrator" (assuming you have the necessary rights - this might not be necessary).
- Enter `cd`, followed by <kbd>Space</kbd>, and that folder name (or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>) (e.g. `cd D:\Downloads\ClientExtension_Latest\`).
- Now the Command Prompt should have navigated there.
- Type `NWLauncher.exe`, and the executable should start.
- If this works, you can add your parameters thusly:

  - `NWLauncher.exe +connect mynwn2pw.example.com`;
  - `NWLauncher.exe -dmc +connect mynwn2pw.example.com +password dmpassword`.

Comment: WOW, I can (and will) follow these instructions!  It sorta reminds me of, many years ago, writing batch (.bat) files.  There was no GUI (windows) at that time.  Just DOS.  I've forgotten much since then. So thank you very much, Joachim!  I'm forever in your debt.  So, I'll study your instructions, execute and see what happens. Thanks again and don't be surprised if I come back.  I'm a little dense these days.   ;)

;-)
rm